# MongoDB PHP (SUM)?

Tags: php, mongodb, sum

as mysql query: `select sum(adet) from stok where isbn=$isbn`. I want to make this query as a mongodb query but I couldn't make. I've read some code examples but I didn't understand how it works.

I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's query language doesn't give us the ability to perform summations, but we can utilize its [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) to do so.

Given the following sample data:

```
> db.stok.insert({ isbn:"foo", adet: 5 })
> db.stok.insert({ isbn:"foo", adet: 3 })
> db.stok.insert({ isbn:"foo", adet: 1 })
> db.stok.insert({ isbn:"bar", adet: 2 })
> db.stok.insert({ isbn:"bar", adet: 4 })
> db.stok.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cde94037a16345b5316987"), "isbn" : "foo", "adet" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cde94437a16345b5316988"), "isbn" : "foo", "adet" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cde94b37a16345b5316989"), "isbn" : "foo", "adet" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cde95337a16345b531698a"), "isbn" : "bar", "adet" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51cde95637a16345b531698b"), "isbn" : "bar", "adet" : 4 }
```

We could summate all of the `adet` values for "foo" `isbn` values with the following pipeline (i.e. sequence of aggregation operators):

```
> db.stok.aggregate(
... { $match: { isbn: "foo"}},
... { $group: { _id: 1, sum: { $sum: "$adet" }}}
... );
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : 1, "sum" : 9 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Here, we're narrowing the considered documents by the `isbn` field with [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/), and then using [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/) to collect all of those into a single bucket and aggregate the `adet` field with a summation.

We could also compute sums for each distinct `isbn` value by using a non-constant `_id` in our grouping:

```
> db.stok.aggregate({ $group: { _id: "$isbn", sum: { $sum: "$adet" }}});
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "bar",
            "sum" : 6
        },
        {
            "_id" : "foo",
            "sum" : 9
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The above examples use the JS shell, but you can execute aggregation queries in PHP with either the [MongoCollection::aggregate()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php) helper method, or by directly invoking the `aggregate` command with [MongoDB::command()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php).